# Find and adjacent cell with criteria

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula, formula, criteria

I have the following spreasdheet:

| pserial | sex | marstatb | age |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10105101 | 1 | 5 | 92 |  |
| 10115101 | 1 | 1 | 63 |  |
| 10120101 | 2 | 4 | 56 |  |
| 10127101 | 1 | 2 | 38 |  |
| 10127102 | 2 | 2 | 25 |  |
| 10135101 | 2 | 1 | 37 |  |
| 10135102 | 2 | -1 | 14 |  |
| 10135103 | 2 | -1 | 10 |  |
| 10137101 | 1 | 2 | 35 |  |
| 10137102 | 2 | 2 | 29 |  |

Where pserial: Serial number of individual
Sex: male/female
marstatb: Marital status including cohabitees

I know that the person is divorced if marstatb= 4, and that the person is female if sex=2

I need to find the pserial value for the oldest divorced female.

I was thinking of using the filtering function, IF function for the criterias but I'm not sure how.
I think the INDEX function would be useful for this too.

UPDATE: This is my function so far:

```
=@FILTER(A2:A9282,MAXIFS(D2:D9282,B2:B9282,2,C2:C9282,4)=D2:D9282)
```

Comment: The serial number is just a way of identification. It is not based on age, or nothing in particular, as age is another different criteria in my database. I forgot to write it, sorry for that! I've just edited my question.

Comment: That displays all the values. I've put @ in front of FILTER and checket it but if gives me a pserial of a marstab that is not 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `FILTER()` & `MAXIFS()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F2`

```
=FILTER($A$2:$D$12,(MAXIFS(D2:D12,B2:B12,2,C2:C12,4)=D2:D12)*(B2:B12=2)*(C2:C12=4))
```

---

Another alternative is using `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F4`

```
=INDEX(A2:D12,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A2:D12)/
((D2:D12=AGGREGATE(14,7,D2:D12/((B2:B12=2)*(C2:C12=4)),
ROW($ZZ1)))*(B2:B12=2)*(C2:C12=4))-1,1),0)
```

---

Using `SORT()` & `TAKE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F6`

```
=LET(x,SORT(A2:D12,4,-1),
TAKE(FILTER(x,(INDEX(x,,2)=2)*(INDEX(x,,3)=4)),1))
```

---

**With Headers:**

```
=LET(x,SORT(A1:D12,4,-1),VSTACK(TAKE(x,1),
TAKE(FILTER(x,(INDEX(x,,2)=2)*(INDEX(x,,3)=4)),1)))
```

---

### EDIT

For **MS365** Users

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `F9`

```
=TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:D12,(B2:B12=2)*(C2:C12=4)),4,-1),1)
```

---

**With Headers:**

• Formula used in cell `F11`

```
=VSTACK(A1:D1,
TAKE(SORT(FILTER(A2:D12,(B2:B12=2)*(C2:C12=4)),4,-1),1))
```

---

Comment: I've translated it and it works. Thanks! What was the problem? Should we delete all the comments?

Comment: @andrea65 The problem was we have to use the conditions twice to get the output, otherwise it `MAXIFS()` was giving false positives. See I have posted an alternative version using `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()`